# Call one controller method from another controller in angular js 1

Tags: angularjs

I wanted to call closeTools() of ToolsController from PaymentAccessController but unable to do so.
Details are added in child controller. Please refer to child controller method onCancel().

//Parent Controller

```
(function(){

angular.module('ssuiTools').controller('ToolsController',ToolsController);
ToolsController.$inject=['$scope'];

function ToolsController($scope){
var vmTool = this;
vmTool.closeTools = closeTools;
init();

function init(){
-
-
}

function closeTools(){
$scope.toolsList = [];
$scope.showToolsContainer = false;
$scope.isMaximised = true;
$scope.isZoomedOut = false;
}
}
})();
```

//Child Controller

```
(function(){

angular.module('ssuiTools').controller('PaymentAccessController',PaymentAccessController);

PaymentAccessController.$inject=['httpService','$scope','$filter','$q'];

function PaymentAccessController(httpService, $scope, $filter, $q){
var vmPat =this;
vmPat.onCancel =onCancel;
init();

function init(){
-
-
-
}

function onCancel(){
//here i want to call closeTools() of parent controller - ToolsController
ToolsController.closeTools();  //tried different ways but didn't work
}
};
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your tools controller

```
(function(){

    angular.module('ssuiTools').controller('ToolsController',ToolsController);
    ToolsController.$inject=['$scope'];

    function ToolsController($scope){
        var vmTool = this;
        vmTool.closeTools = closeTools;
        init();

        $scope.$on('on-cancel-called', function (event,data) { //Catch on-cancel-called event
            closeTools();
        });

        function init(){

        }

        function closeTools(){
            $scope.toolsList = [];
            $scope.showToolsContainer = false;
            $scope.isMaximised = true;
            $scope.isZoomedOut = false;
        }
    }
})();
```

And inside the child controller

```
(function(){

    angular.module('ssuiTools').controller('PaymentAccessController',PaymentAccessController);

    PaymentAccessController.$inject=['httpService','$scope','$filter','$q'];

    function PaymentAccessController(httpService, $scope, $filter, $q){
        var vmPat =this;
        vmPat.onCancel =onCancel;
        init();

        function init(){

        }

        function onCancel(){
            $scope.$emit('on-cancel-called')
        }
    };
})();
```

To learn more about $on,$broadcast and $emit please refer to this [link](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5d8be0b6-e294-457e-82b0-ba7cc10cae0e.aspx)